# Regular expression for only numbers, letters and dashes allowed?

Tags: php, regex

What is the regex for a string that has no white space and only numbers, letters and dashes are allowed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this: `^(?! )[0-9a-zA-Z-]*$`.  The example I used for testing can be seen [here](http://rubular.com/r/EGDwd8h7Qr).

Comment: The `(?! )` is unnecessary. It only prevents a match if the first character is a space, and there is nothing to match spaces anyway.

Comment: @MikeM It is a negative look ahead that says if there is any space, it fails.  It doesn't matter where that space is located.  If you look at the example I linked, you can see it marking the string as a failure when there is multiple spaces at different points in the string.  You can quickly add in a space at the front of the passing strings and it should fail.  The `(?! )` is needed and prevents any spaces from passing.